# Is there a way I can generate source:jar after Proguard obfuscation?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, proguard

Is there a way I can run `mvn source:jar` after **Proguard** obfuscation?

Or

Is there a way I can generate **Obfuscated** `source:jar`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Maven proguard plugin](http://wvengen.github.io/proguard-maven-plugin/proguard-mojo.html)?

Looks like it generates the obfuscated jar.

Another solution is to use an assembly to produce a jar with the obfuscated sources and attach it to the build with sources as classifier.